# Unable to send email using MFMailComposeViewController in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to ios app development, Below is the code I used to send an email.

```
   MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];



    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
                  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                                error:(NSError*)error {

          if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {

              NSLog(@"It's away!");
          }

          [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Unfortunately delegate methods are never triggered , Can any one please suggest how can i check my email via simulator?

Comment: I was facing the same problem..but when i tried on my device it worked fine.. thanks lukya for explanation.

Comment: For my task I just need to display the composer. But I am not able to do so. MFMailComposeViewController* composeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; . This line pops up the alert controller

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You **CANNOT** send mails through Simulator.

Instead you can install the application in device and try from there.

Simulator just displays the composer but wont allow you to send mails. Sent Successfully is just the acknowledgment that your code is fine and there is no issue that terminates it while sending.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and do not be fooled by the sent mail animation, the email is *not* really sent.

Comment: For my task I just need to display the composer. But I am not able to do so. MFMailComposeViewController* composeVC  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; . This line pops up the alert controller.

Comment: As of iOS 13, you cannot display the composer in the simulator. You'll get an assertion: [MFMailComposeViewController] Unable to initialize due to + [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] returns NO.

Answer (score 7):

As far as i know, you cannot send mail from Simulator.. The MFMailComposeViewController uses the mailbox configured in iPhone's Mail app to send the mail. The simulator does not have the Mail app.

Comment: For my task I just need to display the composer. But I am not able to do so. MFMailComposeViewController* composeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; . This line pops up the alert controller

Answer (score 3):

You can able to send mail using the Gmail connectivity you can send mail to user for that you need to insert the some amount of code and setting in your code following code which use for sending a mail.

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject{

    NSLog(@"Start Sending");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];



    NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];

    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

    testMsg.fromEmail = @"Your mail id";

    testMsg.toEmail = @"sender mail ids";

    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";

    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;

    testMsg.login = @"Uour mail id";

    testMsg.pass = @"your pass";

    testMsg.subject = @"Test application ";

    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

    // Only do this for self-signed certs!

    // testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;

    testMsg.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,

                               @"Some text to include in body",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];




        testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];

    [testMsg send];



}


-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message{
    [message release];
    NSLog(@"delegate - message sent");
}



-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error{
    [message release];
    // open an alert with just an OK button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    NSLog(@"delegate - error(%d): %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

And following files copy into your project.

[image]

For downloading a sample [code here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/mail%20transfer%20using%20GMAIL/mailTransfer.zip/download)

Comment: This api work fine without attachment. It will crash when you attach more than two files. I think MFMailComposeViewController better than SKPSMTPMessage