# mail could not send through iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i want to send mail through iphone sdk i know there are lots of answers here on stack overflow but it does not work ,i downloaded the mail composer app from apple site and ran in my simulator ,it displaye that mail has been sent but i dont get it on my email address

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What did you try, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: @shaggy: he wants to send mails using mailcomposer thriugh simulator and he is getting the ack that mail is sent but he is not getting the mail in his inbox. Dats the question. Possible duplication of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520508/cannot-send-email-in-iphone-simulator/3520727#3520727`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YOU CANNOT send mails through simulator`. It just shows mail sent for the acknowledgement that your mail code is working and wont crash or have any errors..

For testing you have to use device. SIMULATOR shows you the composer but will never send mail as the mailclient is not installed in it..

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: thanks i hope u r right and can u plz tell can we schedule our mail to send with iphone sdk

Comment: Dont hope.. I am 110% correct in the above case... By schedule Do you mean that you wanna send the mail after several interval of time?

Comment: yes i can use a date picker for that but how to connect the two so that mail can send automatically

Comment: cannot send mail automatically as for sending mail mail composer needs to be opened. The thing you can do is send the time and mailcontent to the server and do the coding of sending mail automatically on serverside maybe PHP. As per my knowledge(correct me if i am wrong) We cannot send mails automatically or without opening composer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test mail and message compose controllers in simulator. Mail composer uses the default mail account set up on your device to send the mail. There is no mail account set up in the simulator.

Test it on device...