# Can from xcode 4 iphone simulator 4.3, we send email by application

Tags: iphone, email, email-client

There are many similar questions but i want to know can we send email from iphone simulator? i am using xcode 4? Actually i have setup everything. smtp gmail server, everything. but when i run my application it says CAN NOT CONNECT TO SERVER.  So where is the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520508/cannot-send-email-in-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes We can send email from iPhone simulator. i used SMPSMTPMessage mail, a third party library to send emails. It is working perfectly fine. 
I am using Xcode 4 with iPhone simulater 4.3

Comment: Better option is create webserver to send email from there. Much more easy and feasible as if it sends from iPhone and does not send first time due to network failure or something and if it is critical then that will be problem. Simple create webserver send your data i.e email address and text to server and send from there.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator, AFAIK, is incapable of sending email.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the reason why - but you **cannot** send emails from the simulator.  Again not sure if this applies for separate servers of not...?