# send button does not send

Tags: ios, xcode

I have used the following code for sending an email from my iPad app. The email composer opens but when I press the send button nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
        mailComposer  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
        [mailComposer setSubject:@"your custom subject"];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"your custom body content" isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Nothing happens"? It doesn't send the email or doesn't get dismissed (or maybe both...)?

Comment: Just nothing. Composer stays on the screen and nothing dismisses. I am not sure if it is actually sent as I am not sure if I should expect it to actually send if running in simulator mode. I don't receive any mails though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all [you cannot actually send emails from the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520508/cannot-send-email-in-iphone-simulator), so the fact that you do not receive the messages is normal. Now on the dismiss part, here is the relevant part on the documentation:

> Your delegate object is responsible for dismissing the picker when the
>   operation completes. You do this using the
>   **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:** method of the parent view
>   controller responsible for displaying the MFMailComposeViewController
>   object’s interface.

So the only thing left to do is to implement the delegate method and dismiss the controller. Something like this perhaps:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    // Handle any errors here & check for controller's result as well
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also it would be easier for you to just present the controller modally in the first place like this (< iOS6):

```
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

[And here are](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) the `MFMailComposeResult` constants that you should expect.

Comment: perfect - thanks. The self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES]; is depreciated iOS 6 though.

Answer (score 1):

You can not send an email using simulator. You should try it in iPhone. You also have to configure the email account in iPhone to use this feature.

You can use if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) to check if you can send the mail.