# Attaching an email within app?

Tags: ios, csv, email-attachments

So I have had this problem for sometime and just cant get it working! I have been building a survey app that users simply enter information in and its saved to a csv file. Im now at the stage where I need to attached the csv file within the app to an email address...

I have the code as follows, it should work but for some reason is attaching a 'blank' csv file instead of the one with the data in. Im guessing it must be something to do with the file path however cant get it working!!

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"result‌s.csv"];
    NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedFilePath];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailcomposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailcomposer addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"results.csv"];
    [mailcomposer setToRecipients:@[@"gpsflighttrial@gcap.eu"]];
    [mailcomposer setSubject:self.subject.text];
    [mailcomposer setMessageBody:self.message.text isHTML:NO];
}
```

UPDATE:

So I just tested this on my new i-phone and there is no attachment when the email is delivered? Its there in the mail app and in the simulator, however when the message is received the attachment has gone? Can anyone help??

Comment: What does `csvData` look like in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code and it seems ok. Add this code to see what you actually have in that csv file.

```
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:csvData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Output %@",strData);
```

Comment: Hey it is the right csv file! All the data is in there, i can see it!...  However when I send it to another computer to test it doesnt attach? Any idea why it isnt working??

Comment: I assume you are using some device to test it not simulator.

Comment: I can only use the simulator (my iphone is in repair) however i got a friend to use his iphone and he said it was attaching a blank csv file?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot send mails through Simulator. You have to have a device. Until you have to it will be hard to debug..

Comment: Would you suggest though if the file is loading and the code above shows there is data in the file it surely would work on a device?

Comment: Don't know man but there are some topics outhere that you cannot send email from simulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520508/cannot-send-email-in-iphone-simulator

Comment: So I just tested this on my new iphone and there is no attachment? In the simulator its there on the phone it isnt? Any ideas why??

Answer (score 0):

Try to check csvData contents, it's probably empty.

Comment: how would i achieve that??